# How do I prevent Powershell from closing after completion of a script?

Tags: powershell

*Disclaimer* : I am the epitome of a scipting/Powershell rookie, so please bear with me.

I've written a script to return the Active Directory username of any user currently logged into a given workstation.

```
$input = Read-Host "Workstation Name"
$domain = ".*****.***.com"
$computer = $input + $domain
$list = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $computer | select Username,Caption
Write-Output $list
```

However, if I run this from a pinned script in the taskbar, the Powershell window closes before I have a chance to view the results.

I have tried method 2 and 3 from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546150/how-can-prevent-a-powershell-window-from-closing-so-i-can-see-the-error), but to no avail. Method 2 prompts for user input *before* the results are displayed instead of after, even when the code for the prompt is added at the end of the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried all the answers on that question? Like the `Start-Sleep` option?

Comment: Have you tried just adding a `Pause` to the end of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 from the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24621106/45375) - i.e., waiting for the user to press a key before exiting the script - *can* be used, but it requires additional effort:

End your script as follows in order to see the value of `$list` *before* the `pause` command prompts:

```
$list | Out-Host  # Force *synchronous* to-display output.
pause             # Wait for the user to press Enter before exiting.
```

<sup>Note: `pause` in PowerShell is simply a function wrapper around `Read-Host` as follows: `$null = Read-Host 'Press Enter to continue...'` Therefore, if you want to customize the prompt string, call `Read-Host` directly.</sup>

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) explains why the use of `Out-Host` (or `Format-Table`) is necessary in this case; in short:

- In PSv5+, an *implicitly* applied `Format-Table` command *asynchronously* waits for up to 300 msecs.  for additional pipeline input, in an effort to derive suitable column widths from the input data.

  - Because you use `Write-Output` output objects without predefined formatting data that have 2 properties (4 or fewer ), tabular output is implicitly chosen, and `Format-Table` is used behind the scenes, asynchronously.
  - Note: The asynchronous behavior applies only to output objects for whose types formatting instructions *aren't predefined* (as would be reported with `Get-FormatData <fullOutputTypeName>`); for instance, the output format for the `System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo` instances output by `Get-Alias` *is* predefined, so `Get-Alias; pause` *does* produce output in the expected sequence.
- The `pause` command executes *before* that waiting period has elapsed, and only *after* you've answered the prompt does the table print, after which point the window closes right away.
- The use of an *explicit* formatting command (`Out-Host` in the most generic case, but any `Format-*` cmdlet will do too) avoids that problem by producing display output *synchronously*, so that the output will be visible by the time `pause` displays its prompt.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem for scripts that I'm executing "on demand". I tend to simply add a `Read-Host` at the end of the script like so

```
$str = "This text is hardly readable because the console closes instantly" 
Write-Output $str

Read-Host "Script paused - press [ENTER] to exit"
```

Comment: Since `Write-Output $list` in the OP's case - due to the specific data being output - results in _asynchronous_ output, this won't work as intended: the `Read-Host` prompt will show _before_ the `Write-Output` output. To put it differently: this won't work for the OP and generally _may or may not work_ - it depends on the type of the data being output. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375